# Coloring the mean vlines of the distributionsby class in ggplot

Tags: r, class, ggplot2, line, histogram

I am plotting the distribution of a variable by Class and I include in the plot vlines with the means of the 2 distributions which I would like to be colored using the same color scheme. However the vlines appear with the same color.

For a reproducible example I use the hacide dataset from the ROSE package.  The code is the following:

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(ROSE)

data(hacide)
train <- hacide.train
train[cls == 0, x1_mean := mean(x1)]
train[cls == 1, x1_mean := mean(x1)]

ggplot(train, aes(x = x1, fill = cls, color = cls) )+
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), position="identity",alpha = 0.4) + guides(color = FALSE) +
  geom_density (alpha = 0.5)+ ggtitle("Distribution of Predictor x1 by Class") + 
  geom_vline(data = train, aes(xintercept = x1_mean)) +
  xlab("Predictor x1") + labs(fill = "Class")
```

[image]

Comment: I removed the theme since it's unnecessary and from a package you do not declare.

Comment: From `?geom_vline`: _"Unlike most other geoms, these geoms do not inherit aesthetics from the plot default"_. So you need to set the color again in that geom.

Comment: Perhaps look at this [eerily similar plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45026616/facet-grid-returns-error-message-in-ggplot) that was posted yesterday!